# Dimension of the kernel of an application

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello everyone we're studying Jordan Form and for an exercice I found a contradiction. 
I don't know where I've made the mistake. So let an endomorphism $f$ such that :
( the right arrow is the application $f$ , ex: $f(e_{5}) = e_{2}$
$$e_{4} \longrightarrow e_{2}$$

$$e_{5} \longrightarrow e_{2}$$

$$e_{6} \longrightarrow e_{3}$$

$$e_{2} \longrightarrow e_{1}$$

$$e_{3} \longrightarrow e_{1}$$

$$e_{1} \longrightarrow 0$$

I found that : $Im(f) = [0,e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}]$ , when I apply the rank theorem :

$dim(Im(f))+ dim(Ker(f)) = dim(E)$ , I found :

$dim(Ker(f)) = 2$ ; and a basis for $Ker(f)=> \left\{ e_{1}\right\} $ which dimension is $1$

I want to know where is my mistake cause for sure the dimension of a space is the number of vector in it's basis or even here I'm wrong ?

And If I can ask an extra question : for the same graph we were asked to find a Jordan basis but I'm used to matrix not graph

$e_{5}-e_{4} \longrightarrow 0$

$ e_{5} \longrightarrow e_{3} - e_{2} \longrightarrow 0 $

$e_{6} \longrightarrow e_{3} \longrightarrow e_{1} \longrightarrow 0  $

but I'm missing $e_{4}$ and I'm not sure if it's correct. Any help would be a lot appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The dimension of your kernel is $3$, since $e_1$, $e_2-e_3$ and $e_4-e_5$ are three linearly independant vectors that are send to $0$ by $f$. And the dimension of the image is also $3$.

Comment: Hi @AlainRemillard I made up the second part to find a Jordan basis. I played with my vectors to get something. The application f is the part defined in the beginning

Comment: (@AlainRemillard Mon application f est défini plus haut la deuxieme partie j'ai juste joué légèrement avec pour obtenir une base de Jordan nilpotent  )

Comment: Thank's for the french translation, I'm happy to see a bit of french on SE. (Merci pour la traduction française, ça fait du bien de lire du français sur SE)

Comment: I also worked on the first définition you gave. $f$ is a linear application, so $f(e_2-e_3)=f(e_2)-f(e_3)=0$. $e_2-e_3$ is part of your kernel. Same for $e_4-e_5$. Then $,\Ker(f)=\langle e_1,e_2-e_3,e_4-e_5\rangle$ and $Dim(\Ker(f))=3$.

Comment: So there's a inconsistency amongst the rank theorem and what I found (No worries, my mom is a quebécoise)

Comment: Your application is consistent with rank theorem since the dimension of the kernel and the image is $3$. $3+3=6$.

Comment: oh the $0$ does't count ?

Comment: $0$ is never part of a basis.

Comment: Thank you sir, merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put the discussion on the comments in the form of an answer.

First, the dimension of the image is $3$. The $0$ vector is never part of a basis.
$$\text{Im}(f)=\langle e_1,e_2,e_3\rangle$$
So the kernel must have dimension $3$ also. We could see that 
$$f(e_1)=0$$
$$f(e_2-e_3)=f(e_2)-f(e_3)=0$$
$$f(e_4-e_5)=f(e_4)-f(e_5)=0$$
We found three linearly independant vectors, so they form of basis of the kernel.
$$\text{Ker}(f)=\langle e_1,e_2-e_3,e_4-e_5\rangle$$

Comment: Once again, merci beaucoup!

Comment: @Simba27 Glad I could help, content d'avoir pu d'aider. Sadly, I don't know enough about Jordan form to help you with the second part.

Comment: It has been answered, glad that I met a french canadian on SE

Answer (score 0):

Your question about the kernel has been answered. As far as a Jordan basis goes, it should be right there in that graph. Each line represents a *Jordan chain*: each vector in the chain is obtained from the previous one by applying $f$, and the three vectors near the end of each chain form a basis for the null space of $f$, as you know from the other answer. (If the eigenvalue were something other than zero, we would use $f-\lambda\operatorname{id}$ and would be talking about its null space instead.) The other vectors in these chains are called *generalized eigenvectors*. We know that no chain will be more than three long—that is, the largest Jordan block is of order 3—because $f\circ f\circ f\equiv 0$, but $f\circ f$ is not identically zero.

However, there appears to be an error in that graph: $f(e_5)=e_2\ne e_3-e_2$. The first element in the second chain should be either $e_6-e_4$ or $e_6-e_5$. Both of those vectors are preimages of $e_3-e_2$.

Comment: Thanks @amd, but is it ok if there is no $e_{4}$ in the graph ?

Comment: Nevermind I got it